# Is there any way to make FullCalendar an object to reference for the backend? asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, fullcalendar

I have a dropdownlist that every time is being selected it changes the view on the calendar based on the serviceID that is being selected from dropdownlist for that specialty. This is a non-mvc website I'm trying to create for a project, I would like to make the appointments refresh every time you went to a different month? here's my code

**Default.aspx**

```
<script id='FullCalendar' type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                var sl_calendarEl = document.getElementById('sl_calendar');
                
                var sl_calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(sl_calendarEl, {
                    height: '100%',
                    expandRows: true,
                    slotMinTime: '08:00',
                    slotMaxTime: '18:00',
                    headerToolbar: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                    },
                    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                    
                    allDaySlot: false, 
                    navLinks: true, 
                    editable: true,
                    selectable: true,
                    nowIndicator: true,
                    dayMaxEvents: true, 

                    eventa: [<%=DataAsJson%>]
                    
                });
                      
                console.log(sl_calendar.view.currentStart);
                console.log(sl_calendar.getEvents());
                
                sl_calendar.render();
            });
        </script>
```

**DataAsJson**

```
    public string DataAsJson
    {
        get
        {
            
            String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            myConnection.Open();
            
            string varYear = "2020";
            string varMonth = "08";

            
            String query = "SELECT ((isnull(Specialist.[lastName],'')+', ')+isnull(Specialist.[firstName],'')) AS name, CalendarDate, sc.[serviceID], srv.name, [specialistID], S.lastName, S.firstName, [callTypeID], CONVERT(time,LEFT(st.starttime,2)+':'+RIGHT(st.starttime,2)) AS starttime, CONVERT(time,LEFT(et.endtime,2)+':'+RIGHT(et.endtime,2)) AS endtime ";
            query = query + "FROM [sldb].[dbo].[ServiceCalendar] AS sc JOIN [dbo].[StartTime] AS st ON st.id = sc.starttimeID JOIN [dbo].[EndTime] AS et ON et.id = sc.endtimeID JOIN [dbo].[Services] AS srv ON srv.id = sc.serviceID JOIN [dbo].[Specialist] AS S ON S.id=sc.specialistID JOIN Specialist ON Specialist.id = sc.specialistID ";
            query = query + "WHERE RIGHT([calendarDate],4) = "+varYear+" AND LEFT([calendarDate],2) = "+varMonth+" AND sc.Active=1 AND S.active=1 and sc.serviceID = sc.serviceID and sc.serviceID = " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

            Debug.WriteLine(query);

            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            string str = "";

            List<object> myList = new List<object>();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                var indexOfId = reader.GetOrdinal("serviceID");
                var indexOfName = reader.GetOrdinal("name");

                var indexOfCD = reader.GetOrdinal("calendarDate");
                var indexOfStartTime = reader.GetOrdinal("starttime");
                var indexOfEndTime = reader.GetOrdinal("endtime");


                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    var ID = reader.GetValue(indexOfId).ToString();
                    var calendarDate = reader.GetValue(indexOfCD).ToString();


                    var name = reader.GetValue(indexOfName).ToString();

                    calendarDate = calendarDate.Substring(4, 4) + "-" + calendarDate.Substring(0, 2) + "-" + calendarDate.Substring(2, 2);

                    var starttime = reader.GetValue(indexOfStartTime).ToString();
                    var endtime = reader.GetValue(indexOfEndTime).ToString();




                    str = str + "{ title:'" + name + "', serviceID: '" + ID + "', start: '" + calendarDate + "T" + starttime + "', end: '" + calendarDate + "T" + endtime + "'},";


                }

            }
            
            var strL = str.Length;

            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Debug.WriteLine(str);
            Debug.WriteLine(strL);

            if (strL > 5)
            {
                str = str.Substring(0, strL - 1);
            }


            return str;

        }
    }
```

Comment: One thing that stands out is that you are not disposing of the connection object and the reader.

Comment: Hey, I did that after you mentioned it but still doesn't answer my question?

Comment: "I would like to make the appointments refresh every time you went to a different month" ... see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed . Instead of hard-coding your event data into the Javascript, just give fullCalendar a URL where it can go to get the correct set of events, based on the dates being shown at that moment in the calendar.

Comment: @ADyson so I have tried that but it still not working and nothing is being displayed on fullcalendar. There has to be another way surely?

Comment: "it still not working and nothing is being displayed"...well that is the way you should be doing it. There isn't a better way. If it's not working, then you need to show what you tried, and explain more precisely how the code is behaving (e.g any errors etc you've found from your attempts to debug it), then we can help you fix it.

Comment: P.S. You really should not create your JSON by hand like you're doing currently. This can easily introduce unexpected syntax errors into the JSON (e.g. due to the contents of one of the fields, or you can just make a silly typo). .NET, like all languages, has libraries for automatically generating a valid JSON string from an object or list variable. Newtonsoft.JSON is the most popular and full-featured one, you can install it from Nuget. There's absolutely no reason you should ever be creating JSON by hand. It may or may not be the cause of your problem here, but it's certainly a risk.

Comment: P.P.S. I've also just noticed that you're not parameterising your SQL queries, which leaves your database open to SQL Injection attacks and other problems, because you're including user input in the query. Learn how to use parameters correctly to protect your data. See https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx (and many other articles, tutorials etc).

Comment: @ADyson let me try a few things before I post any code first. I have been trying different type of methods but so far nothing yet, I did try that Newtonsoft.JSON but since the database was built differently we tried to make it where its read by the Newtonsoft.JSON and it just didn't work at the time so we decided to build our own and pass it as a string. Thanks for the replies

Comment: @ADyson question for you, when you dabbled in fullcalendar. When using .net core version 3 are you doing it in webmethods? cause I noticed something that a lot of people are using mvc instead of webforms like I am

Comment: Personally I haven't used it with webmethods, but there have been plenty of previous questions asked on this site where people were using a webmethod as the event source, and were successful.  You can use any backend service which will provide the data in the correct JSON format - it really doesn't matter. .NET API, .NET MVC, .NET Webforms, PHP, Java, Python, nodeJS or anything else. The language/framework is irrelevant - as far as fullCalendar & the browser is concerned it's just a HTTP request to return some data. Why? Are you having a specific problem with making it work?

Comment: P.S. .NET Core doesn't have WebForms or WebMethods as far as I know. That's only in .NET Framework. So what version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: @ADyson yeah I'm having trouble, basically in the console its giving me this error **Failure parsing JSON {message: "Failure parsing JSON", xhr: XMLHttpRequest}** I'm wondering if the webmethod isn't working for what I want

Comment: Yes it might not be. Presumably it's generating invalid JSON (or no JSON at all, or a combination of JSON + other content, which will be unparseable). You need to use your browser's Network tool to look at the AJAX request, and check the contents of the raw response to see if it's valid JSON or not.

Comment: @ADyson I'm developing in visual studio 2019 .NET Framework 4.7.2, we're thinking the webmethod doesn't work in this version... we believe that microsoft is basically pushing more towards the mvc instead

Comment: because even like a normal simple webmethod where we have a user enter their name or input and it would call the current date. It's not doing that, it's completely not understanding what a webmethod is... it returns in the response of code.

Comment: There's no reason WebMethods wouldn't work. They're not deprecated or removed in any version of .NET Framework. True they're not supported in .NET Core but that doesn't prevent them from being used in earlier versions. You could always run it under 4.5 or something instead if you really think it's an issue, but I doubt that's the real cause.

Comment: If you want some practical help with it, please edit your question to show your current code (both JavaScript and C#) and detail exactly what result you're getting when you try to execute it.

Comment: P.S. Another option instead of Webmethods which I used to use a lot when I was cursed with having to develop in WebForms (believe me, MVC, Razor pages etc are actually a lot easier to work with once you get used to it), was to create a little WCF service (.svc file) which can be configured to work as a webservice and automatically serialise and deserialise JSON. That always worked very well and I never needed webmethods.

Comment: hey @ADyson we have been trying the mvc for fullcalendar and so far it's going well. Thanks for helping out! Will repost and edited, once it's complete.

Comment: That's good to hear. By all means, if you have a working solution please post it as the Answer, in the section below. That might be helpful for others too.